# sh 'alias' is not giving any output in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a docker container which runs Jenkins.

Inside Jenkinsfile, I try to define an alias and print this alias.

I tried it manually, connecting to Jenkins container, and I am able to do:

```
alias foo='bar'
```

and then, if I execute `alias` I can see the list of alias ( I have 7 preset alias, and the new one )

but when I execute the same thing in Jenkinsfile, I `foo` command won't respond...

Here is my pipeline code:

```
#!/bin/groovy

pipeline {
agent any
stages {
  stage("Use alias command"){
    steps { 
        sh 'alias foo="bar"'
        sh 'foo'
    }
  }
}}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Most likely because you didn't define the alias for your jenkins user. Also note that "alias" are not permanent you need to set them during shell init (.bash_profile or...)

Comment: I would be confortable for an alias that lasts only for the build. It would avoid me to do a : if ! file contains alias insert alias...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `sh` command runs in it's own shell. It's in the same agent/workspace, but since it's a new shell, environment variables, aliases, etc, will be lost. You need to combine the lines into a single `sh`:

```
#!/bin/groovy

pipeline {
agent any
stages {
  stage("Use alias command"){
    steps { 
        sh '''
          alias foo="bar"
          foo
        '''
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: I posted another newbie question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436614/error-unable-to-open-galaxy-yml-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-galaxy